# How to read txt in certain condition

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have text file like below.

```
A1 1234 56
B2 1234 56
C3 2345167
```

I have the startposition and length table.
which represents each where each elements start in previous df,and length for each rows.

```
start length
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      2
6      2
8      2
10     1
```

I would like to read like below according to startposition and length.

```
A 1 nan 12 34  5 6
B 2 nan 12 34  5 6
C 3 nan 23 45 16 7
```

first,I tried

`pd.read_csv(file.txt,sep=" ")`

But I couldnt figure out how to split.

How can I read and split dataframe?

Comment: Where is this "below"?  You neglected to include your coding attempt.  Also, note that this is *not* a CSV format file; it appears to be simply text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fixed width file, you can use `pandas.read_fwf`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""A1 1234 56
B2 1234 56
C3 2345167""")

pd.read_fwf(s, widths = widths.length, header=None)

#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
#0  A   1   NaN 12  34  5   6
#1  B   2   NaN 12  34  5   6
#2  C   3   NaN 23  45  16  7
```

---

The `widths` data frame:

```
widths = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""start length
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      2
6      2
8      2
10     1"""), sep = "\s+")
```

Comment: I like your answer much better than mine :) Can I mention that you may need to use a unicode string for `StringIO` to prevent a `TypeError`

Comment: @K.J.Phan Thank you! Usually this doesn't cause a problem, and the StringIO here is for demonstration purpose. But yeah, a more rigorous way might be declaring it as Unicode. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't a CSV format, and so I had to produce a work-around.

```
def get_row_format(length_file):

    with open(length_file, 'r') as fd_len:

        #Read in the file, not a CSV!
        #this double list-comprehension produces a list of lists
        rows = [[x.strip() for x in y.split()] for y in fd_len.readlines()]

        #determine the row-format from the rows lists
        row_form = {int(x[0]): int(x[1]) for x in rows[1:]} #idx 1: to skip header

    return row_form

def read_with_row_format(data_file, rform):

    with open(data_file, 'r') as fd_data:

        for row in fd_data.readlines():

            #Get the formatted output
            #use .items() for Python 3.x
            formatted_output = [row[k-1:k+v-1] for k, v in rform.iteritems()]
            print formatted_output
```

The first function gets the 'row-format' and the second function applies that row format to each line in the file

Usage:

```
rform = get_row_format('lengths.csv')
read_with_row_format('data.csv', rform)
```

Output:

```
['A', '1', '12', '34', '5', '6']
['B', '2', '12', '34', '5', '6']
['C', '3', '23', '45', '6', '7']
```

Comment: Please look at @Psidom answer below, mine only has more upvotes because it was posted earlier, but Psidom's answer is much more elegant. I'll leave this here for those who only want to use native data-types

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the starting position and length of each field, use them.
Here is code to carry that out.  Each line is taken in turn.  Each field is the slice from the start column to the same position plus the length of the field.

I leave the conversions to you.

```
data = [
    "A1 1234 56",
    "B2 1234 56",
    "C3 2345167"
]

table = [
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [6, 2],
    [8, 2],
    [10, 1]
]

for line in data:
    fields = [line[(table[col][0]-1) : (table[col][0]+table[col][1]-1)] for col in range(len(table))]
    print fields
```